# How can I delete group of rows in yii cgridview?

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I found some code is solving this task but it don't work.

```
echo CHtml::link('Delete', '#', array(
'onclick'=>' 
    var id_list=$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("My-grid","check-boxes");
    if (id_list=="") {
        alert("checkbocks do not checked!!!");
    } else {
        MyMagicFunction(id_list);
    }
return false;',
```

));

line don't work

```
 var id_list=$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("My-grid","check-boxes");
```

I tried change parameters but it didn't give any result.

Comment: are you getting any error in js console?

Answer (score 0):

You must have checkboxes with the name `check-boxes[]` (Watch the brackets!) in your gridview, the code will check for them.

Also, the code will return an array. Use `.length` instead of the `== ""`.

```
echo CHtml::link('Delete', '#', array(
    'onclick'=>' 
        var id_list=$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("My-grid","check-boxes");
        if (id_list=="") {
            alert("checkbocks do not checked!!!");
        } else {
            MyMagicFunction(id_list);
        }

        return false;',
    )
);
```